# bind domain names to applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, domain, bindings

I know you can't actually bind a domain to an application, but my company server is set up in a way that all websites are applications of one single website. These websites have so far been accessed through an IP address, but now my company would like to start binding domain names to all of these websites, and we don't know if and how this works.

I am not in charge of the server, but I do have access to it and I am looking for a way to help our server admin out. I have little experience using IIS Manager (version 7.5), so any pointers would be appreciated.

I have attached a screenshot of how these websites are setup, below:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2qu58wm.jpg

Here is a screenshot of the bindings of the Default Web Site:

http://i43.tinypic.com/ta3csx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. Add all the domains to the `Bindings` section of the Default website, and use the IIS URL Rewrite module to rewrite requests to the applications based on the hostname provided in the requests
2. Create a new Web Site for each existing application, add 1 unique binding for each (eg. `"*:80:a1drukwerk.company.local"`), and choose the physical directory of the existing application as the application path

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying option 2 first, but it's not working yet. I add a new Web Site, and I point the physical path to inetpub/wwwroot/a1drukwerk/ (for example). Then I set the Host name to a domain that is currently pointing to the correct IP address, but when I visit the site I get a 500 - Internal server error. Did I follow your instructions correctly? Should I add the site as an application to the newly created Web Site? (I updated my first post with some more info, see the second image I posted.)